# Ideal multi column index ordering for a low-cardinality match and a high-cardinality range

Tags: postgresql, index, select

In postgres, I am doing a query on 2 columns

- string `type` with only 3 possible values
- timestamp `the_timestamp`

the query is

```sql
select id from my_table where type = 'a-value' and the_timestamp < '2024-03-01'
```

1. What is the best ordering for the index for this query?
   I believe there are these suggestions, which conflict

   - equality first, ranges later
   - "highest cardinality first" (only for match, not range?)
2. Does it make much difference if the index on the_timestamp is `desc` or `asc`, or does that only make a difference when traversing multiple columns with range queries... or doing `BETWEEN`, something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Highest cardinality" doesn't make much sense with a inequality. It probably doesn't make much sense with a range either unless the range is always very narrow.

The best ordering for that query is clearly `(type, the_timestamp)`.  You might want to include "id" at the end so you can get an index-only scan.  However, the reverse order of the columns is likely to be "good enough" for this query, while it would be far more useful for a query which didn't specify type.  So if you don't want to have an index for every query, then the `(the_timestamp, type)` could very well be better overall.

Where the ASC and DESC matters is if you want to support a query with something like `ORDER BY A DESC, B ASC`.  Otherwise, it doesn't really matter because PostgreSQL knows how to read an index either forward or backward